# remove keys that are present in sibling object and have a certain value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following input file:

```
{
    "dic": {
        "a": "",
        "b": "",
        "c": "",
        "d": ""
    },
    "remove": {
        "b": true,
        "c": false,
        "d": true
    }
}
```

I want to remove with jq all elements of the dictionary `dic` which are also in the dictionary `remove` with the value true.

This would be the output:

```
{
    "dic": {
        "a": "",
        "c": ""
    },
    "remove": {
        "b": true,
        "c": false,
        "d": true
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do this. I would first need to clean the `remove` dic and only get the keys with the value true. Then I would need to somehow only delete these keys from `dic`.

Comment: Does it need to be using only `jq`? That can be done using `jq` and `bash`.

Comment: Bash would also be ok. But I don't want to use any other external interpreter like node or python. Just bash and jq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need anything other than JQ for that.

```
[.remove | path(.[] | select(.))] as $p | .dic |= delpaths($p)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4cCuXMQn9W)</sup>

If there might be other values in `remove` than **true** and **false**, use

```
select(. == true)
```

instead of

```
select(.)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward and efficient solution using jq alone:

```
(.remove | with_entries(select(.value == true))) as $remove
| .dic |= with_entries(select($remove[.key] | not))
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using bash loops:

```
#!/bin/bash
# saving the json so we can manipulate it freely
data="$(cat data.json)"
for k in $(echo "$data" | jq '.remove' | jq -r keys[]) # getting all the keys from remove
do
    # skipping the key if it isn't supposed to be removed
    [ $(echo "$data" | jq .remove.$k) == 'false' ] && continue
    data="$(echo "$data" | jq "del(.dic.$k)")" # removing the key
done
echo "$data" # final json without the keys
```