# remove top-level JSON keys that are present in second JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use `jq` to remove keys from the first file that exist in the second file.

Given:

**a.json**:

```js
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

**b.json**:

```js
{"b": true}
```

Required contents of **diff.json**:

```js
{"a": 1}
```

Question:

What's the `jq` syntax to subtract these two JSONs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a very similar question yesterday, [my answer to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63472740/10248678) can be adapted for this case as shown below.

```
$ jq 'delpaths([input | path(.[])])' a.json b.json > diff.json
$ cat diff.json
{
  "a": 1
}
```